# How to prove the existence of this $A$ such that $\mu(A)=0$ under these conditions?

Tags: measure-theory, functions

> Let $(X, \sum, \mu)$ be a measurable space. Supose that $f_{n}:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}\cup \{-\infty\}$ are non-negatives and measurables functions for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. If
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{X} f_{n} d\mu = 0,$$
>
> prove that exist a set $A \in \sum$ such that $\mu(A) = 0$ and
>
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) =0$$
>
> for all $x \in A^{c}$.

I was trying to use $$\int_{X} f_{n} d\mu = \sup \{\int_{X} \phi(x) d\mu, \phi \in F_{n}\}$$

where $F_{n}$ its a set where $\phi$ are simples, measurables, non-negatives and $\phi(x) \leq f_{n}(x)$ for all $x \in X$, but I get nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

In general, the assertion does not hold true.

Consider $((0,1),\mathcal{B}((0,1))$ endowed with the Lebesgue measure (restricted to $(0,1)$) and define

$$\begin{align*} f_1(x) &:= 1_{(1/2,1)}(x) \\ f_2(x) &:= 1_{(0,1/2)}(x) \\ f_3(x) &:= 1_{(3/4,1)}(x) \\ f_4(x) &:= 1_{(1/2,3/4)}(x) \\ f_5(x) &:= 1_{(1/4,1/2)}(x) \\ \vdots & \end{align*}$$

Then it is not difficult to see that each $f_n$ defines a measurable and non-negative function and $\int_{(0,1)} f_n(x) \, dx \xrightarrow[]{n \to \infty} 0$. On the other hand, $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ does not exist for almost all $x \in (0,1)$. This means, in particular, that we cannot find a Lebesgue null set $A$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists for all $x \in A^c$.

**Remark:** If you assume additionally that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ exists for all $x \in X$, then the assertion holds true. This follows easily from Fatou's lemma.